# Looking for Microsoft Silverlight PivotViewer cxml schema

Tags: silverlight, schema, pivotviewer, cxml, cxml-collectionxml

I'm looking for the schema (XSD) for CXML files of [Microsoft Silverlight PivotViewer](http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/pivotviewer/).

Does anyone have it?  The usual [link](http://schemas.microsoft.com/livelabs/pivot/collection/2009) does not ever work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately Microsoft has deleted all references to PivotViewer.
However you can still access most of it from the Wayback Machine
http://web.archive.org/web/20120529021514/http://www.silverlight.net/learn/data-networking/pivot-viewer/collection-xml-schema

Comment: Not just PivotViewer, they made a mess of everything on silverlight.net website